# How to find whether a given month already exists in a database table

Tags: sql

If I have data like this

```
case 1

   code    start month    end month
  winter     january       march 
  summer     march         april
  spring     may           december

case 2

   code    start month    end month
  winter     march         march 
  summer     april         january
  spring     february      february
```

and if I am trying to enter again start month and end month. I should validate 
if the month I am giving is already present in the table for any of the seasons.

I want to do the validation with help of a query so that I will not enter duplicates.

The months are in strings only . The values doesnot include the year –
 i am looking to ensure the new month i entered in the new row will 
not fall in between the already given months in the previous records 
the periods also overlap around the year.

Comment: This question is not clear and does not provide enough information.

Comment: Your question isn't clear yet.  There are multiple issues to resolve.  Are the months encoded as strings, or in some numeric form.  Do the values include a year?  Are you looking to ensure that the new row does not overlap with existing rows?  Do periods wrap around the end of the year?  (Probably yes because of case 2, April-January; but then we need to know about the years.)

Comment: The months are in strings only . the values doesnot include the year

Comment: yes i am looking to ensure the new month i entered in the new row will

Comment: not fall in between the already given months in the previous records the periods also overlap around the year.there will no no years specified when the data is enetered

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
declare @startmonth varchar(10)
declare @endmonth varchar(10)
set @startmonth = 'march'
set @endmonth = 'may'
declare @stmonth int
declare @edmonth int

set @stmonth = DATEPART(mm,CAST(substring(@startmonth,0,4) + ' 1900' AS DATETIME))
set @edmonth = DATEPART(mm,CAST(substring(@endmonth,0,4) + ' 1900' AS DATETIME))
print(@stmonth + ' ' + @edmonth)

declare @checkexist int
set @checkexist = 0
declare @te int
if(@edmonth < @stmonth)
begin
    set @te = @stmonth
    set @stmonth = @edmonth
    set @edmonth = @te
end
set @te = @stmonth
while (@te < @edmonth)
begin
declare @count int
SELECT @count = count(code) from tablename where DATEPART(mm,CAST(substring(start_month,0,4)+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) <= @te and DATEPART(mm,CAST(substring(start_month,0,4)+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) >= @te
if(@count > 1)
    begin
    set @checkexist = 1
    break
    end
set @te = @te + 1
end

if(@checkexist = 0)
begin
 --'insert statement
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Server solution:

```
INSERT INTO atable (code, [start month], [end month])
SELECT u.code, u.[start month], u.[end month]
FROM (
  SElECT
    *,
    start_month_num = MONTH(CAST([start month] + ' 1, 2000' AS datetime)),
    end_month_num   = MONTH(CAST([end month]   + ' 1, 2000' AS datetime))
  FROM (
    @code AS code,
    @start_month AS [start month],
    @end_month AS [end month]
  ) x
) u
  LEFT JOIN (
    SElECT
      start_month_num = MONTH(CAST([start month] + ' 1, 2000' AS datetime)),
      end_month_num   = MONTH(CAST([end month]   + ' 1, 2000' AS datetime))
    FROM atable
  ) t ON u.start_month_num BETWEEN t.start_month_num AND t.end_month_num +
           CASE WHEN t.end_month < t.start_month THEN 12 ELSE 0 END
         OR
         t.start_month_num BETWEEN u.start_month_num AND u.end_month_num +
           CASE WHEN t.end_month < t.start_month THEN 12 ELSE 0 END
WHERE t.code IS NULL
```

`@code`, `@start_month`, `@end_month` are the values to be inserted. The values are inserted if the specified range doesn't overlap with any range already stored in the table.